# Finding "lsort" indices in .tcl

Tags: tcl

How can we obtain indices of lsort?

For example:

```
lsort -real {1 -4 6 0}
```

how can I obtain indices for the code above as idx = (1, 3, 0, 2)?

Answer (score 4):

The `-indices` option to `lsort` does exactly what you want:

```
set values {1 -4 6 0}
set indices [lsort -indices -real $values]
foreach idx $indices {
    puts "[lindex $values $idx] is at $idx"
}
```

Output:

```
-4 is at 1
0 is at 3
1 is at 0
6 is at 2
```